# How would I pass in the request class to my abstract class?

Tags: php, design-patterns, laravel, laravel-5

I'm developping an API and because I have (mostly) the same functionality I've created an abstract class to be extended on my controllers.

My abstract class looks like: http://laravel.io/bin/23Bzj

Where in the controller I would construct with a model and response (will probably move the response to ApiController constructor later).

```
class EventController extends ApiController
{

  public function __construct(Event $model, ResponseRepository $response)
  {
     $this->model = $model;
     $this->response = $response;
  }
}
```

But the question is: how will I be able to use the specific `Request` class in my ApiController to be used the in the methods for validation/what is the best practice.

I can use a normal `Request` class but then I won't have any validation before the methods.

When I'm in my `EventController` I will be able to use `UpdateEventRequest` and `CreateEventRequest` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know if you use in your controller in any method

```
public function edit(UpdateEventRequest $req) {
  // any code
}
```

before launching `// any code` part validation will be done.

What you could try to do:

1. Change your `update` method in abstract class to protected
2. Change signature of this method from `public function update(Request $request, $id)` to `public function update($request, $id)` - I don't know it this step will be necessary
3. Create new method for example `realUpdate` with the following code:

   ```
   public function realUpdate(UpdateEventRequest $req, $id) {
      parent::update($req, $id);
   }
   ```

I'm not sure about step 2 because I don't know if Laravel will try to run any validation if you use `Request` in your abstract class. It's also possible that it will run this validation again for `UpdateEventRequest` - you should give a try, I haven't tested it.

Basically you will have code similar to this:

```
<?php

class X
{

}

class Y extends X
{

}


abstract class ApiController
{

    protected function update(X $x, $id)
    {
        echo "I have " . get_class($x) . ' and id ' . $id;
    }
}


class Controller extends ApiController
{

    public function realUpdate(Y $y, $id)
    {
        parent::update($y, $id);
    }
}

$c = new Controller();
$c->realUpdate(new Y, 2);
```

and Laravel should run at least once validator based on rules from `UpdateEventRequest`.

You cannot have the same name for this method in child class because you will get a warning:

> Strict Standards: Declaration of Controller::update() should be
>   compatible with ApiController::update(X $x, $id) in ... line 31

It will however still work but I assume you don't want to have any warnings.